# F# and Web API Json for analysis in DataFrame

Tags: json, f#, deedle, fsharp.data.typeproviders

Im trying to learn F# by rewriting some scripts from python, where I query a graphql endpoint and load the json into a Pandas DataFrame for cleaning and analysis:

json like this:

```
apiResponse = {"data":
                    {"Shipments":{"ErrorMessage":null,
                    "Success":true,
                    "ValidationResult":null,
                    "TotalCount":494,
                    "Data":[
                       {"Building":"B7",
                        "Comment":"Test",
                        "CompletedDate":"2021-04-12T10:13:13.436Z",
                        "ItemId":"dd4520bb-aa0a-...",
                        "NoOfUnit":5,
                        "Organization":{
                              "OrganizationId":"cac43a32-1f08-...",
                              "OrganizationName":"XXX"},
                       "Adress":"Road 5"
                      },
                      {"Building":"B7",
                      ....}]}}}
```

Python:

```
data = request.json()
#only the "Data" path
json_list = data['data']['Shipments']['Data']
df = json_normalize(json_list)
```

The same approach with using Fsharp.Data, while "file.json" is only the "Data[]" part ( I tried to create a fiddle, but I could not get it to run. [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ABYjT8):

```
type ApiTypes = JsonProvider<"file.json"> //where file.json has only "Data" path of apiResponse
let jsonResponse = JsonValue.Parse(apiResponse)
let data = jsonResponse?data
let Shipments = data?Shipments
let Data = Shipments?Data

let input = 
 ApiTypes.Parse(Data.ToString())

let df = Frame.ofRecords input
```

But this is not working.
So my questions:

1. Is this the right way to work with this json?
2. Is there a better way to create a DataFrame with json?

Any help apreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Deedle, but I think `ofRecords` [requires an actual static type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322745/c-sharp-create-deedle-dataframe-from-json-response) to work correctly, so it may not be compatible with `JsonProvider`. (I couldn't get it to work, at least.)

Instead, I would define the type by hand and then deserialize to it, like this:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

type Datum =
    {
        Building : string
        Comment : string
        CompletedDate : DateTime
        ItemId : Guid
        NoOfUnit : int
        Organization :
            {|
                OrganizationId : Guid
                OrganizationName : string
            |}
        Adress : string
    }

let jobj = JObject.Parse(apiResponse)
let frame =
    jobj.["data"].["Shipments"].["Data"].Children()
        |> Seq.map (fun jtok -> jtok.ToObject<Datum>())
        |> Frame.ofRecords
```

Comment: Okay, this would have been my next approach, defining types on my own.  I will give it a try. Why did you call the type "Datum"? I ask, because the JsonProvider did the same when I loaded the complete Json. Is the naming of `data` and `Data` in the structure a problem here?

Comment: “Datum” is just singular for “data”.  I deliberately used the same name that `JsonProvider` did. The name isn’t a problem.

Comment: And in German, "Datum" means "date", that was confusing me.....

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just for completion, I had to deal with some `null` values for the `DateTime` types with ` Nullable<DateTime>`. Now I have only to find out, how to deal with empty arrays in the json.

Comment: Actually, the problem is not an empty array, it is a list like `"ShipmentContent":[{"Item1": "xxx", "Item2": "yyy"}]` that gives me the error.

Comment: I would suggest creating a separate SO question for this problem, where you can put the details.

Comment: I will do, but first I have to read the docs a bit more...