# F# Define Types for Json with nested list

Tags: json, f#, json.net

Follow up question to this [question, to parse json to deedle dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560583/f-and-web-api-json-for-analysis-in-dataframe).

My json includes some list with nested lists:

```
apiResponse = {"data":
                    {"Shipments":
                               {"ErrorMessage":null,
                                 "Success":true,
                                 "ValidationResult":null,
                                 "TotalCount":494,
                                 "Data":[
                                         {
                                         "CompletedDate":"2021-04-12T10:13:13.436Z",
                                          "ItemId":"dd4520bb-aa0a-...",
                                          "Organization":{
                                                      "OrganizationId":"cac43a32-1f08-...",
                                                      "OrganizationName":"XXX"
                                                      },
                                          "ShipmentContent" : [
                                                           {
                                                             "MaterialId": "cac43a32-1f08-..",
                                                             "unit": "kg",
                                                             "quantity": 2.0, 
                                                             "labels" : ["A1", "A2", "A3"]
                                                            }, 
                                                            {
                                                             "MaterialId": "cac43333-1f08-",
                                                             "unit": "t",
                                                             "quantity": 0.4, 
                                                             "labels" : ["B1", "B2", "B3"]
                                                             }
                                                             ] 
                                     },
                                     {......,
                                     ....}]}}}
```

My code so far:

```
type ApiTypes = 
  {
    ItemId : Guid
    CompletedDate : Nullable<DateTime> 
    Organization: 
      {|
        OrganizationId : Guid
        OrganizationName : string
       |}
    ShipmentContent : // ? How to define the List
      {|
        MaterialId : Guid 
        Quantity : Nullable<decimal> 
        Unit : string
        Labels: List // ?
              
      |}
  }
```

How can I define these types? The next step would be:

```
let jsonObject = JObject.Parse(graphResponse)

let frame =
  jsonObject.["data"].["Shipments"].["Data"].Children()
      |> Seq.map (fun jtok -> jtok.ToObject<ApiTypes>())
      |> Frame.ofRecords
```

Can I define all in one type, or do I have to define a seperate type for ShipmentContents?

I realy apreciate your help!

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F2oWkU) (doesn't work, but for sharing the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you want to have it all in one type:

```ml
type ApiTypes = 
  {
    ItemId : Guid
    CompletedDate : Nullable<DateTime> 
    Organization: 
      {|
        OrganizationId : Guid
        OrganizationName : string
      |}
    ShipmentContent :
      {|
        MaterialId : Guid 
        Quantity : Nullable<decimal> 
        Unit : string
        Labels: string[]
      |}[]
  }
```

Note that I've defined the lists as arrays, since arrays are the collection type supported by JSON.

Comment: Thanks, that's the trick. Can you recommend any tutorial or documentation about that? I was looking around but could not find any that helped me with that.

Comment: Here are a couple of articles that talk about using anonymous record types for JSON serialization: [one](https://www.compositional-it.com/news-blog/5-tips-for-working-with-f-anonymous-records/), [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records#properties-of-anonymous-records).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understanding the topic.